# System.out.println always outputs HASH(0x........)

Tags: java, android, string, hash

The System.out.println statement below always outputs to the logcat a hash reference like "HASH(0x....)" whether or not I specify the variable to be printed as "line" or "line.toString()". How do I get it to print the actual string value?

```
URL object=new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

try {
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
} catch (ProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

OutputStreamWriter wr;
try {
    wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(json.toString());  
    wr.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}                       

int HttpResult = con.getResponseCode(); 
if (HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(),"utf-8")); 
    String line;  
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
        System.out.println("Line: " + line.toString());
    }  
    br.close();  
}
```

Comment: Yes, the json.toString() works fine.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you print `line` or `line.toString()`, the `println()` method will use the `toString()` method in both cases. The problem must be at the other end, since your code for reading and printing looks just fine.

Comment: Show your logcat output. What are you trying to do with the code? Are you reading json response?

Comment: 06-27 00:22:09.788: I/System.out(1753): HASH(0x29ddfcf8). I'm trying to debug the response yes.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code. You could replace all the code above the loop with something simpler, like:

```
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("somefile");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream,"utf-8")); 
        String line; 
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
            System.out.println("Line: " + line);
        }  
        br.close();
```

And you will see the content of the file.

Note that I didn't need to do a `.toString()` because the variable is already a string.

What I suspect here is that the server is sending you a compressed body, and each line as a hash because that is the definition of the compression, which is all in hex.

The content is json, but it was compressed to improve size and speed.